# Why do i double my display in json

Tags: php, mysql, json

So i fetch my data from two tables in my php and encode it in one json object. I got everything i needed except that it doubles the display. And my teamone is located in the matches tables. instead of starting from array 0, it starts after the schedules tables. Which is array 7. I dont know why this happen.

Here is my php.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * from schedule, matches;";  
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("start"=>$row[4],"end"=>$row[5],"venue"=>$row[6], "teamone"=>$row[8], "teamtwo"=>$row[9], 

"s_name"=>$row[17]));

}


echo json_encode (array("schedule_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my display. As you can see there are four displays but in my database it only has 2. It doubles the display. How do i fix this? Thanks

```
{ "schedule_response":[
             {"start":"2016-11-10 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-04 00:00:00","venue":"bbbb","teamone":"aaa","teamtwo":"bbb",
            "s_name":"hehehe"},
            {"start":"2016-11-23 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-24 00:00:00","venue":"bbbbbbbb","teamone":"aaa","teamtwo":"bbb",
            "s_name":"hehehe"},
            {"start":"2016-11-10 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-04 00:00:00","venue":"bbbb","teamone":"ehe","teamtwo":"aha",
            "s_name":"aaa"},
            {"start":"2016-11-23 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-24 00:00:00","venue":"bbbbbbbb","teamone":"ehe","teamtwo":"aha",
            "s_name":"aaa"}]}
```

I need to get the teamone, teamtwo and s_name values from the matches while i need the start, end and the venue from the schedule table in one query.
[Schedule table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5HFl.jpg)

[Matches Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCaEg.jpg)

Comment: just print your array and check if there is double entry for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your SQL query, you should **not forget** to perform some form of a grouping (the way you select results from both table defines that):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * from schedule s, matches m GROUP BY s.id";  //I assume that your table schedule has an `id`
```

Or, you can rework the query to be more readable:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.*, m.* FROM schedule s 
       INNER JOIN matches m ON m.schedule_id = s.id 
       GROUP BY s.id"; //I assume that you have such database design that you have defined foreign key on table `matches`.
```

Of course, the `INNER JOIN` above could be `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - it all depends on your database design.

Comment: well it works. But the values from the matches table teamone,teamtwo and s_name are returning null

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the problem with mysqli_fetch_array().

```
Can you please change mysqli_fetch_array()  to mysqli_fetch_assoc()
```

Comment: It gives all data as null values. And undefined offset on many lines.

Comment: Please access the values using field_name not using index. For example if 'venue' is your db table column name then $row['venue'];

Comment: still gives me double display sir

Comment: Just print your $response array , what it is showing, double entry?

Comment: it just prints the name Array sir

Comment: Same entry twise right?. Then it is the problem with your query

Comment: How do i fix this sir? can you post some codes if possible? thanks

Comment: You are simply using natural join, Please change your query by adding some condition in WHERE section of your query . Only if I get the exact table structures and whats your requirement in query then i can help you

Comment: Posted it sir. Thanks

Comment: Which field is common in 2 tables?..foreign key?

Comment: m_id is foreign in schedule table sir

Comment: Just change the $sql to,  $sql = "SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name,start,end,venue  FROM `matches` as A INNER JOIN  `schedule` as B ON A.m_id = B.m_id";

Comment: it doesnt loop anymore sir. But all values gives me null

Comment: you used LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN?. You need to use INNER JOIN

Comment: Just place the query in phpmyadmin and check

Comment: I used left and all values are null. When i used inner it gives me only this {"schedule_response":[]}

Comment: Just place the query in phpmyadmin and check and show me the result